# Uninstall ubuntu on windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu (14.04) on my Windows 8.1 (4 Go RAM, 64 bits) by means of a bootable USB. After having partitioned the HDD, the installation was successful.

However, I had an issue to boot into Ubuntu, so I decided to uninstall it by means of a software (that I discovered on youtube) I tried to doing so, but it  got worse, as after trying to reboot my Lap, a black screen shows 'grub>'.

So, now, each time I try to get into my Windows 8.1, I have to enter a specific script and then my laptop boots normally.

*How shall I proceed to uninstall the Ubuntu boot loader?*

Comment: @LiveWireBT So what if he asked the wrong question? From your comment, you've got a pretty good idea of what's gone wrong with his setup. OP's shouldn't have to word things perfectly for you to offer help.

Comment: Makes a huge difference if system is UEFI or BIOS boot. And then if grub installed to gpt protective MBR and booting grub in BIOS mode when Windows is there in UEFI boot mode. May just need setting in UEFI, may need Windows repairs to restore boot loader as posted below. But without details not sure which fix will work.

Comment: @amanthethy No I don't have a clue which program he used to make the situation worse. And no, I cannot assume with confidence what the cause of the *actual* problem is. (Also nobody else, but the user is responsible for backups.) OPs should provide as accurate information as possible if they expect as accurate and **short** answers as possible. MMV, but think about it: non-repetitive answers, just straight to the point solutions when you put your question into your favorite search engine. It could even be possible for the booting topic, yet it isn't. There's a reason why.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Yeah... But none of what you mention prevents you from politely guiding the user to either provide the info you need or a to link to where this has been answered before.

Comment: @amanthethy I tried my best to be polite and not have the comment being removed or flagged as as rude/non-constructive. :) I'm sure throwing more than 3 links at a user would also have been as impolite as the reminder to backup/restore and suggesting that installing the Windows bootloader is the right question to ask. Feel free to comment, I will read what you write, but I will not reply (to avoid being too chatty.)

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Windows Recovery Enviroment (http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN207399/EN) then lunch CMD by going Troubleshooting > Advanced Options and run command prompt then execute this

> bootrec.exe /fixmbr

This should uninstall grub (Ubuntu bootloader) and replace with Windows bootloader.

Comment: Thanks for your response; However, I re-installed ubuntu again; and now it seems resolved. But, my issue is still persisting; as I can't boot into ubuntu; it's really annoying; I think the pbm is the Windows 8.1 I shoud maybe downgrade to Windows 7!!!!!

Comment: I dont think this will fix your problem.